Can't init firebase cloud storage due to cloud resource location
I’m using Firebase emulators to develop and test Cloud Functions locally, and one of my use cases involves uploading a file to Cloud Storage. As part of this process, I initialize Firebase emulators with the Cloud Storage service as follows:
npx firebase init emulators

=== Emulators Setup
? Which Firebase emulators do you want to set up? Press Space to select emulators, then Enter to confirm your choices. Storage 
Emulator
? Which port do you want to use for the storage emulator? 9199
? Would you like to enable the Emulator UI? Yes
? Which port do you want to use for the Emulator UI (leave empty to use any available port)? 
? Would you like to download the emulators now? Yes

Then I tried starting firebase emulators for cloud storage, but got an error:
npx firebase emulators:start --only storage

Error: Cannot start the Storage emulator without rules file specified in firebase.json: run 'firebase init' and set up your Storage configuration

This makes sense because the storage.rules file needs to be created before the emulators can start up Cloud Storage. So, next I ran:
npx firebase init storage

=== Storage Setup
Error: Cloud resource location is not set for this project but the operation you are attempting to perform in Cloud Storage requires it. Please see this documentation for more details: https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/locations

I went to the Firebase Console, enabled storage, and selected the service location, matching the location of all other Firebase services I’m using. However, even after a few hours, I keep receiving the same error message, as if my local Firebase setup doesn’t recognize that the storage service has been activated.
Environment Details:
•   macOS Sequoia 15.0
•   VS Code 1.95.1
•   Node.js v18 (also tried with v20 and v22)
•   Firebase CLI 13.23.1


After enabling the storage, and selected the service location, can you try to logout from your local terminal with firebase logout and login again with firebase login with making sure you select your corresponding project with firebase use PROJECT_ID ?
Also check if this answer helps you to solve your issue ?

"I went to the Firebase Console, enabled storage" On projects created since October 1st, you must be on the paid plan to be able to use Cloud Storage. Is this a new project, and if so: did you upgrade to the paid plan?

@RohitKharche logging out and back in again hasn't fixed the problem. I included storage.rules directly in firebase.json, and the emulators have initialized properly this time. The fact that I can’t initialize storage correctly might cause some side effects in the future, so I will keep pursuing how to fix it.

@FrankvanPuffelen the firebase project was created before October 1st, however, the could storage service was only activated after October 1st. Anyways, I'm in the Firebase Pay-as-you-go (Blaze) plan. In the Billing & Usage settings, it shows Cloud Storage is currently in "no-cost tier for paid infrastructure products"

OK, so that's not it then (I'm extra on the lookout for folks affected by this recent change). And indeed: Storage still has a free tier (quiet similar to the previous free tier), it's "just" not on the free plan anymore. --- I hope somebody else spots the problem.

I even tried creating a new firebase project, upgraded the plan to Blaze and run: npx firebase init storage, but got the same error message. I highly doubt firebase or gcp teams would not anticipate this as a major problem, so there's gotta be something related to my account. I will keep investigating and bring the answer if I can.

It looks like a new pull request is coming to fix this. Hopefully, it will remove the resource location requirement during storage initialization. FUP here: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/7901

A fix was released in firebase-tools v13.24.1. See https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/releases/tag/v13.24.1 and https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/pull/7905. Upgrading to the latest version(or at least v13.4.1) should resolve this.
